# change value of tag respecting conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, xml-parsing

I want to read a csv file.

The first column refers the `tag source`, the second column refers to the `value source`, the third column refers to the `target value` to change . The last column refers to the `tag name` changed.

How can I do it dynamically please?

```
 Types1, Init, INITIAL, Type1

 Types1, inits, INITIAL, Type1

 Types2, ANNULE, delayed, Type2

 Types3, Topp, high, Type3

 Types3, best, TOP, Type3
```

**Input sample**

```
<data>
  <db1>
    <Types1> Init </Types1>
    <Types1> inits </Types1>
    <Types3> best </Types3>
  </db1>
  <db1>
    <Types2> ANNULE </Types2>
    <Types3> Topp </Types3>
    <Types3> best </Types3>
  </db1>   
<data>
```

**Expected Output**

```
<data>
  <db1>
    <Type1> INITIAL </Type1>
    <Type1> INITIAL </Type1>
    <Type3> TOP </Type3>
  </db1>
  <db1>
    <Type2> delayed </Type2>
    <Type3> high </Type3>
    <Type3> TOP </Type3>
  </db1>
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi i did it with accessing the tags manually without passing by the csv file.

Comment: what is you input data, post few rows, and expected output?

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi Thnak you for your response. Original post Edited

Comment: input and output are json files?

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi xml files

Comment: can you pass dataframe in reproducible format for csv file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For csv data like below:

[image]

You need to use `pandas` to manage csv and `ElementTree` to manage xml file.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
root = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse('data.xml')

for tag in df['tag'].unique():
    for item in root.iter(tag):
        text = item.text.strip()
        data_row = df[(df['tag']==tag) & (df['old']==text)]
        item.text = data_row['new'].values[0]

root.write('file_new.xml')
```

**Output:**

```
<data>
  <db1>
    <Types1>INITIAL</Types1>
    <Types1>INITIAL</Types1>
    <Types3> best </Types3>
  </db1>
  <db1>
    <Types2>delayed</Types2>
    <Types3> Topp </Types3>
    <Types3> best </Types3>
  </db1>   
</data>
```